# Is an ATM legally obliged to display withdraw fees in the United States?

Tags: united-states, fees, atm

Is an ATM legally obliged to display withdraw fees in the United States?

Comment: Legally required or not, i'd think they'd jump at the chance. I disclose a $5 fee for using my ATM, that's $5 you can't later accuse me of stealing.

Answer (score 8):

**Yes** (for the fees *it* is charging you)

Per the [Electronic Funds Transfer Act](https://www.fdic.gov/regulations/laws/rules/6000-1350.html), section 904(d)(3)(C):

> No fee may be imposed by any automated teller machine operator... unless (i)  the consumer receives such notice in accordance with subparagraph (B); and (ii)  the consumer elects to continue in the manner necessary to effect the transaction after receiving such notice.

Subparagraph (B) states that the notice must

> appear on the screen of the automated teller machine, or on a paper notice issued from such machine, after the transaction is initiated and before the consumer is irrevocably committed to completing the transaction.

It used to be the case that a sticker near the ATM was required in addition to it being displayed on-screen or on paper, however that requirement was [removed by Congress in 2012](http://files.consumerfinance.gov/f/201303_cfpb_Final-Rule-Amendment-to-Reg-E-re-ATM-Disclosures.pdf).

It does not seem to be required to tell you about what your own bank will charge you... but then, you should probably not rely on a third party to tell you what your bank charges you.